# c# pinvoke SndGetSoundFileList?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke

I'd like to call [SndGetSoundFileList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431631.aspx) from c#, but I got no idea how the p/invoke for this function needs to be, due to the pointer parameters.

```
HRESULT SndGetSoundFileList (
   SND_EVENT seSoundEvent,
   DWORD grfLocations, 
   SNDFILEINFO** ppSoundFiles,
   int* pcSoundFiles
);
```

I'd like to get the list as a string-array, of course.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the array parameter, use `out IntPtr` as the parameter type. Then use Marshal.PtrToStructure to retrieve the structures, and call LocalFree to free the memory when you're done.

Comment: Using out IntPtr is easy, but I can't get Marshal.PtrToStructure to convert the ppSoundFiles to an array of the structure. Is there a trick there?